# C++ Loop not working right

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, output

I want to be able to enter something into "text" and have it ask if i want to continue and repeat, but when i type 'y' to continue, it says "Enter whatever: " again and then goes right to asking if i want to repeat again without it letting me type in text

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char ans = 'y';
    string text;

    while (ans == 'y')
    {
        cout << "Enter whatever: ";
        getline(cin,text);

        //blah blah blah

        cout << "Again?(y/n): ";
        cin >> ans;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

output

Enter whatever: gfdshsg fdsgfdsgfds fdgsfdsg

Again?(y/n): y

Enter whatever: Again?(y/n):

Answer (score 1):

Use :-

`cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');`

( <sup>Header File : `#include<limits>`</sup> )

after `cin >> ans;`

to eat trailing newline

`std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()` is used to retrieve the maximum number of characters the input buffer can hold, it allows `ignore()` to remove as many characters as possible up to the new line.

Ref: [***`cin.ignore( )`***](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore)

Answer (score 1):

`getline(cin,text)` extracts an entire line from `cin`, including the newline character. On the other hand, `cin >> ans` extracts a single character from `cin` and nothing else. That means the newline character that you added when you inputted the letter `y` is still there. Then when it loops round and you get back to `getline` again, it already has a line to extract (up until the remaining newline character).

One way around this is to extract and discard all characters after the `y` character up until and including the newline character:

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Answer (score 0):

Put cin.ignore() between getline and cin